# jQuery Resize plugin

Tags: jquery, resize

I spent hours of searching for this but without any success.
I need a plugin (jQuery) that is  similar to jQueryUI's .resizable() applet.
I need to resize a div by a grip in left bottom and I cant use jQuery UI.
Any help will be apriciated.

Comment: What *can* you use?  It might help to know what already precludes you from using jQuery UI, so we don't recommend an alternative that can't be used for the same reason.

Comment: jQueryUI is just too big and to use only .resizable() i must include tones of other things that i will never use. With one jQuery plugin i have to include only it.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [jqDnR](http://dev.iceburg.net/jquery/jqDnR/). It is a bit old but working.

Comment: I saw that, but it works with position: relative;. My div is position: absolute;

Comment: @BuggyGeek: It should work. I used it too and on the website it says: *If an element is to be resized or dragged, it MUST have its positioning set to **ABSOLUTE**, RELATIVE, or FIXED.* Have you tried?

Comment: Well it doesn't work when i try it. I see it in the site, I even copied the EXACTLY same code on my files and it doesn't work. I dont know why.